# Resolving Circular Dependency in NodeJS model

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have two models (using BookshelfJS, or BackboneJS, doesn't matter): `modelA`, `modelB`. `modelA` requires `modelB` and `modelB` requires `modelA`.

Initially, I had:

```
// modelA
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf);
var modelB = require('./modelB');
var modelA = Bookshelf.Model.extend({});

module.exports = modelA;

// modelB
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf);
var modelA = require('./modelA);
var modelB = Bookshelf.Model.extend({});

module.exports = modelB;
```

Then I read [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry) about the `Bookshelf.plugin('register')`. So I changed my code to:

```
// modelA
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf);
var modelB = Bookshelf.model('modelB');
var modelA = Bookshelf.Model.extend({});

Bookshelf.model('modelA', modelA);

// modelB
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf);
var modelA = Bookshelf.model('modelA');
var modelB = Bookshelf.Model.extend({});

Bookshelf.model('modelB', modelB);
```

In case 1, there was a circular dependency, which was fixed in case 2. But now in case 2, when `modelA` is being bootstrapped, `modelB` is not defined yet, so `Bookshelf.model('modelB')` doesn't exist.

What do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so the fix was quite easy. Here it is for anyone who is interested. `require` the model inside the `.extend({})`'s function that will use it. For instance:

```
// modelA (which requires modelB somewhere inside)
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf);
var modelA = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'modelA',

    someFunc : function() {
        var modelB = Bookshelf.model('modelB'); 
        // Now use modelB here
    }
});
```

Problem is that `modelB` is not bootstrapped when `modelA` is being bootstrapped. Requiring the `modelB` at the top of the page is then impossible. Instead, you require it inside the function. By then, your app is running and everything is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0):

So @Kousha helped me out about being able to require inside `Bookshelf.Model.extend` I make a file for each of my model/model groups and then export the model. So I did this variation.

modelA.js

```
var modelA = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'modelA',

    modelB() {
        this.belongsToMany(require('./modelB).modelB);
    }
});

module.exports = { modelA };
```

modelB.js

```
var modelB = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'modelB',

    modelA() {
        this.belongsToMany(require('./modelA).modelA);
    }
});

module.exports = { modelB };
```